# Microsoft Access DB - can't figure out how to update source data

Tags: ms-access

So i have an access database that i've been asked to update for 2024. Its a risk database that was designed by someone who has since left the company, and no one else seems to have any ideas how it was made.

My Access is very limited, but I've been able to update the source table in the access DB for 2024, and blank out the required fields for the new year (renewal amounts etc...). I've also relinked the tables via the Linked Table Manager, but when i run the reports, it still seems to be pulling from the previous source database.

[Linked Table Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjKOp.png)

The only thing i can think is the Object Dependencies, where i can see the table that it pulls from tbl_Customer, and definitely seems to be taking the 2023 data.

[Object Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJt5S.png) / [2023 data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHXl3.png)

There is also the Description field in the Property Sheet for the table, but i thats just a description...right?

[Description field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXBLO.png)

Am i able to just update the Object Dependencies and point them at the new source? Its an identical table except for the location and content. I know i could probably just replace the original db, but we need the 2023 data for audit purposes.

**Update** - I noticed the source database wasn't showing in my Linked Table Manager, so i thought i should add that. When i add it though, it gives itself the name tbl_Customer1, as if there's already a tbl_Customer. Where else could i find the table if its not in Linked Table Manager?

[Updated images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oReoH.png)

Comment: In the case of linked tables, Description is the link info. This is filled in by Access. You have not changed the linked file.

Comment: Why have separate file for each year? This is not a coding issue, it is design, and question not really appropriate for SO. It is possible to programmatically change table link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically change the connection of a linked table in ms access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682332/programmatically-change-the-connection-of-a-linked-table-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i figured it out with some help from Google. There was a hidden tbl_customer table in the Object Viewer, and that was still pointing at the old source db. Once i relinked that, it worked perfectly.

Thanks all for the help.