# How to toughen an MS Access database against frequent network disconnections

Tags: ms-access, networking

My team and I utilize MS Access databases across a network that disconnects frequently. Whenever a disconnect happens, there's a cascade of failure messages in Access and any records mid-entry are lost.

We know what's causing this, but it's beyond the level of my authority to fix. It's related to Windows 10 re-mapping the network drive whenever there's a group policy update, causing it to 'lose' the network drive for a split-second; long enough to disconnect the database.

As resolving the network disconnects will involve the IT department escalating it to the national level (Government computer system), I need a fix "now" so my form files don't generate a dozen errors and need to be restarted every time this happens.

What settings or code could I use to harden the forms files against network disconnects?

EDit: To answer questions

1. The data is kept in a separate file from the forms, allowing multiple people to work on the database at the same time.
2. I believe it's pointing to a drive letter for where the data file is. I don't know how to setup a server address location. My method of connecting was to browse to the file.

Comment: Are you linking backend on drive letter path or server name path? Server name (UNC) path might help but I don't know for sure. I use VBA procedure to set links in the frontend before distribution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473263/update-an-access-linked-table-to-use-a-unc-path

Comment: What do you mean by 'form files'?

Comment: Split database into front end and back end, with a frontend copy on each local computer and the back end on the shared network drive. This will not solve all problems, but should prevent corruption of "form files" (assuming this means Access forms). There can still likely be problems with data lost/corruption on the back end.

Comment: You say you are losing data when records are mid-entry.  Are your forms bound?  Could you unbind your forms and save data through a button only once complete and if network connection is present?